# Having trouble installing ggplot2

Tags: r, installation, package

This is my output:

```
install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)

Installing package(s) into ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/2.13’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ggplot2’ is not available (for R version 2.13.1)
```

I'm having the same problem with the package "sp" as well, not really sure what to do about it. Working in Fedora kernel version 2.6.35.14-106.fc14.x86_64

Comment: The newest R version is 2.15.2 and quite a bit has changed since 2.13.1. I'm guessing you need a newer version of R.

Comment: Yes, the error message means what it says. The latest ggplot2 (0.9.3) depends on R > 2.14: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html, as does the latest sp (1.0-2).

Answer (score 0):

Latest `ggplot2` version depends on R >= 3.0. You can check available R version at [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html) for current version of `ggplot2`.